# Is there a name for implementation of bank funds transfer algorithm that uses like an "event store"

Tags: c#, database, algorithm, serialization, transactions

Sorry for bad title. I don't know how else to describe what I'm thinking.

Suppose for example there is the following interface

```
public interface IBank
{
     void AddAccount(string account);
     void AddFunds(string account, int amount);
     void SubtractFunds(string account, int amount);
     int GetFunds(string account);
     void TransferFounds(string accountFrom, string accountTo, int amount);
}
```

and we want to implement the `TransferFunds`. We know this is requests atomic operation equal to an `AddFunds` and `SubtractFunds`.

I was brainstorming that one way to solve this is to keep like an "event store". Suppose adding each record (each numbered point) below can be done transactionally. We can have one record which represents the transaction and has two operations.

1. Add $5 to X
2. Add $7 to Y
3. Add $4 to Z
4. Subtract $2 from Y
5. Add $3 to Y
6. [Transfer $4 from X to Y]

   - Subtract $4 from X
   - Add $4 from Y

Then `GetFunds("X")` and `GetFunds("Y")` would each be computed by going through 1-6. It is guaranteed that they will be either be ($5)-$4=$1 and ($7-$2+$3)+$4=$12 or $5 and ($7-$2+$3)=$8 but **never** ($5)-$4=$1 and ($7-$2+$3)=$8 or $5 and ($7-$2+$3)=$8.

Is there a name for this strategy I think I have invented? :)

Comment: It's called running sum, and your "event store" is an ACID compliant database e.g. MSSQL, Postgres or MySQL

Comment: `We know this is requests atomic operation equal to an AddFunds and SubtractFunds.` If only that is how banks _actually_ worked. ;P

Comment: [CQRS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs)?